# Create a Sub ID from a multiple ID columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's say I have a data similar to the below:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 'col2': [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11],
 'col3': ['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'X', 'Z', 'Z']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
print(df)

    col1  col2 col3
0      1    11    X
1      1    11    X
2      1    11    Y
3      1    11    Y
4      1    11    Z
5      2    12    Y
6      2    12    Y
7      2    12    Z
8      2    12    Z
9      2    12    X
10     3    11    Y
11     3    11    X
12     3    11    Z
13     3    11    Z
```

I want to create a `['subID']` column for unique values of the main Id columns `['col1', 'col2', 'col3']`, so something like this:

```
    col1  col2 col3  subID
0      1    11    X      1
1      1    11    X      1
2      1    11    Y      2
3      1    11    Y      2
4      1    11    Z      3
5      2    12    Y      1
6      2    12    Y      1
7      2    12    Z      2
8      2    12    Z      2
9      2    12    X      3
10     3    11    Y      1
11     3    11    X      2
12     3    11    Z      3
13     3    11    Z      3
```

I can achieve this by creating a temp. dataframe with the unique values of `['col1', 'col2', 'col3']`, then iterrow over that and populate the new `['subID']` column in the main dataframe, however, given i have a really large dataset, loops/iterrows is just not ideal given it takes a lot of time to run through. so i was hoping i can find a way as simple/efficent as:

```
df['subID'] = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).cumcount()+1
```

Note the above line of code doesn't really produce what i'm after but just an example of a method to do the job. Do you guys have any idea on whether or not there's a way of doing this?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this would do

```
groups = df.groupby(['col1','col2'])

df['subID'] = groups['col3'].shift().fillna(df['col3']) != df['col3']

df['subID'] = (groups['subID'].cumsum() +1).astype(int)
```

Output;

```
    col1  col2 col3  subID
0      1    11    X      1
1      1    11    X      1
2      1    11    Y      2
3      1    11    Y      2
4      1    11    Z      3
5      2    12    Y      1
6      2    12    Y      1
7      2    12    Z      2
8      2    12    Z      2
9      2    12    X      3
10     3    11    Y      1
11     3    11    X      2
12     3    11    Z      3
13     3    11    Z      3
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also do:

```
df['subID']=(df[['col2','col3']].ne(df[['col2','col3']].shift()).any(1)
             .groupby(df['col1']).cumsum().astype(int))
```

---

```
print(df)
    col1  col2 col3  subID
0      1    11    X      1
1      1    11    X      1
2      1    11    Y      2
3      1    11    Y      2
4      1    11    Z      3
5      2    12    Y      1
6      2    12    Y      1
7      2    12    Z      2
8      2    12    Z      2
9      2    12    X      3
10     3    11    Y      1
11     3    11    X      2
12     3    11    Z      3
13     3    11    Z      3
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
df['subID'] = df.assign(dupes=~df.duplicated()).groupby('col1')['dupes'].cumsum().astype(int)
```

Result:

```
  col1  col2 col3  subID
0      1    11    X      1
1      1    11    X      1
2      1    11    Y      2
3      1    11    Y      2
4      1    11    Z      3
5      2    12    Y      1
6      2    12    Y      1
7      2    12    Z      2
8      2    12    Z      2
9      2    12    X      3
10     3    11    Y      1
11     3    11    X      2
12     3    11    Z      3
13     3    11    Z      3
```